# How to get last uploaded photo at first in photo album

Tags: angularjs

I want to display the last uploaded photo at first in photo album as it is displaying at last after getting uploaded. How can I achieve this in AngularJS . Any help would be great.

Comment: If you're using `ngRepeat`.. `<any ng-repeat b in blabla | orderBy: '-attribute_here'"></any>`

Comment: Thanks, it worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

In the sql with you select the photos, order by photo id desc?